# Routing not working in angular spa

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying my hands on angular routing,but its not working and i am also not getting any error in console.Can somebody please guide me what i am doing wrong?

****app.js****

```
var routingApp = angular.module('routingApp', ['ngRoute']);
routingApp.config(function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/views/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    });
});
```

**mainController**

```
routingApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.message = 'Hey its home page';
}
)
```

;

**aboutController**

```
routingApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.message = 'this app is about routing';
});
```

**index.html**

**

```
 <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <nav class="nav navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    Angular JS Routing
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="main">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="controller/mainController.js"></script>
        <script src="controller/contactController.js"></script>
        <script src="controller/aboutController.js"></script>

**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is missing directive `ng-app`, instead of add ng-controller to `body`, please add `ng-app="routingApp"`

Please alse improve link co **contact page**, instead of `#/Contact`, please use `#/contact`

Answer (score 0):

please check your `href`

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#/Contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: my partial views are inside view folder.how to redirect on these.I tried these,but it is not working.Index.html is outside view folder